# customizing @service annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee

```
I tried with xml configuration it is working fine.I am trying to customize @service tag for RMI.I created a jar with the classes, by the below link.I got the code from the below link.
        https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/barebones-spring-mvc/tree/master/reference/spring-remoting-annotation.
```

added client code.
Instead of creating a httpinvoker service bean i am creating the bean by jar and annotating the class with @service annotaion. When i start the server i am not getting the logs in my jar class.So may be my jar is not getting loaded at run time and giving me error.

```
    My code:
    Client side :

    1) web.xml: Code for web.xml

          <servlet>
                <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>

            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>`

    2) remoting-servlet.xml: Code for remoting servlet

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans ./xsd/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context ./xsd/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

                <context:component-scan base-package="com.apple.*" />  


                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

                <bean id="viewResolver"
                        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
                        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />


            </beans>


    3) Bean class:Code forbean class
        package com.apple.helloClientBean;

        import java.io.Serializable;

        public class ClientBean implements Serializable{

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private String fName;
            private String lName;

            public void setfName(String fName) {
                this.fName = fName;
            }
            public String getfName() {
                return fName;
            }
            public void setlName(String lName) {
                this.lName = lName;
            }
            public String getlName() {
                return lName;
            }
        }


    4) Interface: Code for interface

        package com.apple.helloworldService;

        import com.apple.helloClientBean.ClientBean;


        public interface HelloWorldClient {

            public ClientBean getDetails();
        }


    5) class :Code for class
        package com.apple.helloworldServiceImpl;

        import org.springframework.remoting.Service;
        import org.springframework.remoting.ServiceType;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

        import com.apple.helloClientBean.ClientBean;
        import com.apple.helloworldService.HelloWorldClient;

        @Component("HelloWorldClient")
        @RequestMapping("/getRmiDetails")
        @Service(serviceInterface = HelloWorldClient.class,serviceType = ServiceType.HTTP)
        public class HelloWorldClientImpl implements HelloWorldClient{

            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ClientBean getDetails(){
                System.out.println("I am in HelloWorldClientImpl");
                ClientBean cBean =  new ClientBean();
                cBean.setfName("MahaveerP");
                cBean.setlName("Agrawal");
                return cBean;
            }
        }




 1. Client application context:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans ./xsd/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context ./xsd/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


            <context:component-scan base-package="com.apple.*" />  


            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

            <bean id="ProxyHelloWorld" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
                <property name="serviceUrl">
                <value>http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldClient/remoting/getRmiDetails</value></property>
                <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.apple.helloworldService/HelloWorldClient"/>
            </bean> 


            <bean id="viewResolver"
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
                    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />


    </beans>


    2. client class:
    package com.apple.HelloWorldMTImpl;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    import com.apple.HelloWorldMT.HelloWorldMT;
    import com.apple.helloClientBean.ClientBean;
    import com.apple.helloworldService.HelloWorldClient;

    @Component
    @RequestMapping("/getRMI")
    public class HelloWorldMTImpl implements HelloWorldMT{

        @Autowired
        HelloWorldClient hello = null;

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void getRmiDetails() {
            System.out.println("i am in Helloworld MT");
            ClientBean cb = hello.getDetails();
            System.out.println("fName: "+cb.getfName()+"  "+ "lName: "+cb.getlName());
        }
    }


    3. Client web.xml
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">



        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.apple.HelloWorldMT
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

            <!-- Listeners -->
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>


        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>InitialScreenServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>InitialScreenServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>




    I am getting the below exception:

        18:59:29,829 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/HelloWorldMT].[InitialScreenServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet InitialScreenServlet threw exception: java.io.IOException: Did not receive successful HTTP response: status code = 405, status message = [Method Not Allowed]
            at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.validateResponse(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:179) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:92) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at $Proxy120.getDetails(Unknown Source) at com.apple.HelloWorldMTImpl.HelloWorldMTImpl.getRmiDetails(HelloWorldMTImpl.java:23) [:]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_31]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_31]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_31]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_31]
            at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [:3.1.1.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [:1.0.0.Final]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_31]



        Thanks & Regards
        Mahaveer
```

Comment: I have added client code..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things for you to check first.

1. Try to access the link `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldClient/remoting/getRmiDetails` via your browser and make sure its doing what it needs to do.
2. If it works, then you can atleast isolate the problem is with your client.

In your client application context xml, you declared

`<property name="serviceInterface" value="com.apple.helloworldService/HelloWorldClient"/>`

which is wrong instead,

`<property name="serviceInterface" value="com.apple.helloworldService.HelloWorldClient"/>`

Then do the similar check for your client, try to access your client link via browser.

Comment: Hi Sajan,I added the following  @RequestMapping(value="/getDetails",method= RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody annotation with getDetails method and small changed in URL :http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldClient/remoting/getRmiDetails/getDetails. Now my call in coming to client but when response is going it is giving the below exception  java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4D616861.  header shd application/x-java-serialized-object type but header is coming the same.